# How to create customize the email templates in magento 2

Tags: email-templates, magento2.2.6

I wish to add **custom email templates** for the following

1. Welcome store email
2. Password reset email
3. Order confirmation email

If I created, **email template** from **backend**, But how do I call my custom templates instead of **core email templates**, Please provide me a solution.

Comment: this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmwEhsdHKGE) could help you

Comment: HI @mileven , the video is useful

Comment: try https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-customize-email-template-transactional-email-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all please create your custom template after that you can select your template from the admin side.

Please Follows below steps.

**1.Welcome store email**
Stores->configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration-> Welcome Email
**2.Password reset email**
Stores->configuration->Customers->Password options-> Reset Password Template
**3.Order confirmation email**
Stores->configuration->Sales Emails -> New order Confirmation Template